# Как выбрать данные из таблицы по похожим данным их массива?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть массив (массив приходит от пользователя и каждый раз содержит разные значения и их количество, но допустим, что от пользователя пришел данный массив)

```
$arr = {Один, Два, Три, Четыре, Пять}
```

Есть БД на MySQL, выглядит примерно так:

```
id|name |dat
1 |user1|Один
2 |user2|Один Шесть
3 |user3|Два Три
4 |user4|Пять Десять
5 |user5|Десять Двенадцать
6 |user6|Пять
```

и т.д.

Делаю запрос

```
$arr_lists = '\'' . implode ( "','",  $arr ) . '\'';
$req = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `dat` IN(". $arr_lists . ") ");
```

И у меня выводятся данные только из `id` 1 и 6.
Подскажите, как мне сделать запрос так, что бы он искал похожие данные, типа как работает команда `LIKE`, что бы мне выводились `id` 1, 2, 3, 4, 6

Предугадать, какие данные придут от пользователя, я не могу

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mytable.id
FROM mytable, ( SELECT 'Один' val
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Два'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Три'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Четыре'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Пять'
              ) parameters
GROUP BY mytable.id
HAVING SUM(INSTR(mytable.dat, parameters.val);
```